# Multiple DevOps REST methods throwing 'command failed with an unexpected error'

Tags: azure-cli2

I'm having trouble running DevOps API's via 'az rest'  The two methods I attempted return the same result

The code snippet I'm working with

```
$resource = "https://graph.microsoft.com"
$uribase = "https://dev.azure.com/{org}/{project}"
$requestpath = "/_apis/build/builds?api-version=6.0-preview.6"
$uri = $uribase+$requestpath
az rest --uri $uri --headers "Content-Type=application/json" --resource $resource
```

I've tried several different API versions down to 5.1 but the result is the same.  If i remove the --resource parameter it complains about not being able to determine the authentication.  Is 'https://graph.microsoft.com' the right resource for this call?

The error returned

```
> az : Not a json response, outputting to stdout. For binary data suggest use "--output-file" to 
write to a file
At line:5 char:1
+ az rest --uri $uri --headers "Content-Type=application/json" --resour ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (Not a json resp...write to a file:String) [], RemoteException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError 
The command failed with an unexpected error. Here is the traceback:
'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u221e' in position 6302: character maps to <undefined>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\a\1\s\build_scripts\windows\artifacts\cli\Lib\site- 
packages\azure\cli\command_modules\util\custom.py", line 18, in rest_call
  File "C:\Users\VSSADM~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-yh2ypeu1\requests\requests\models.py", line 
897, in json
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\CLI2\lib\json\__init__.py", line 354, in loads
  return _default_decoder.decode(s)
....
```

I've written the output to a file. It's an HTML file that is related to sign in/sign out - nothing obvious from the text, but kindof a clue.  As a result, I've been attempting to explicitly login to devops (even though I am logged in via 'az login') like this:

```
az devops login --organization https://dev.azure.com/{org}
```

The login hangs every time, I have to shut down powershell to restart.  I've rebooted my machine, tried with and without the organization parameter,  tried re-logging in via az login which works fine, but I cannot get the devops login command to work.

I'm not sure if the login is the issue or if its something else.  Anyone else seen a situation like this? Thoughts on what to try?

Comment: `az devops login`  is used personal access token to log in:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/cli/log-in-via-pat?view=azure-devops&tabs=windows

Comment: Hi, thanks, i set my PAT via $env:AZURE_DEVOPS_EXT_PAT = '3aggid....' and tried logging in but it hangs.  I am able to use CLI DevOps commands (az pipelines, etc.) so it's only the REST interface that fails.

Answer (score 0):

I've untangled most of this mess, hopefully someone else will benefit from this.

First, the hang.  I never fixed this so it may still be related to the workaround I discuss below.

Fix #1: Instead of passing --resource, I punted on that and pass an authorization token in the header.  The "/_apis/build/builds?api-version=6.0-preview.6" now the request method works with this authorization.

Fix #2: I was working with two different REST requests, one retrieves a simple list of builds, the other retrieves a simple list of release definitions.  The base url is different for the release definition API requests, it requires 'vsrm.dev.azure.com'  (i have no idea why).

```
$tokeninfo = az account get-access-token | convertfrom-json
$token = $tokeninfo.accessToken

$uribase = "https://vsrm.dev.azure.com/{org}/{project}"
$requestpath = "/_apis/release/definitions?api-version=6.0-preview.4"
$uri = $uribase+$requestpath
$authheader = "Authorization=Bearer " + $token
az rest --uri $uri --headers $authheader

$uribase = "https://dev.azure.com/{org}/{project}"
$requestpath = "/_apis/build/builds?api-version=6.0-preview.6"
$uri = $uribase+$requestpath
$authheader = "Authorization=Bearer " + $token
az rest --uri $uri --headers $authheader
```

Hope this helps someone out